# Sending mouse position in SFML event

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm stuck on working out the correct syntax to pass the mouseX and mouseY position to my class.

My attempt was like this:

```
 // Start the game loop
 while (window.isOpen())
 {
     // Process events
     sf::Event event;
     while (window.pollEvent(event))
     {
         // Close window : exit
         if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
             window.close();
         }
     }

     // Clear screen
     window.clear();

     // Draw the sprite
     window.draw(sprite);
     window.draw(lsprite);

     if(btn_quit.IsIn(sf::Event::MouseMoveEvent::x,sf::Event::MouseMoveEvent::y){
         btn_quit.RenderImg(window,"button_on.png");
     } else {
         btn_quit.RenderImg(window,"button.png");
     }
  ///rest of the code not relevant to this issue
```

This is in my class:

```
bool IsIn( int mouseX, int mouseY )
{
    if (((mouseX > m_x) && (mouseX < m_x + m_w)) 
    && ((mouseY > m_y) && (mouseY < m_y + m_h ) ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error with the inputs of x and y how ever which says this:

`error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'sf::Event::MouseMoveEvent::x'`

`error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'sf::Event::MouseMoveEvent::y'`

Comment: Um... it's just like the error message says. You are attempting to access the x and y members as if they were static, but they clearly aren't.

Comment: Looks like you should be calling `btn_quit.IsIn(event.x, event.y)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to statically access non-static member fields of a struct. You can't do that. Try something like this:

```
// Start the game loop
while (window.isOpen())
{
    // Process events
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        // Close window : exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            window.close();
        }
        else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseMove)
        {
            if(btn_quit.IsIn(event.MouseMoveEvent.x, event.MouseMoveEvent.x){
                btn_quit.RenderImg(window,"button_on.png");
            } else {
                btn_quit.RenderImg(window,"button.png");
            }
        }
    }

    // Clear screen
    window.clear();

    // Draw the sprite
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.draw(lsprite);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently doing is incorrect in a few ways. First of all you can't access x and y as static data like that, it simply does not exist.

Next to that, SFML events are essentially unions, meaning their actual contents will depend on the type of event you try to handle. You cannot get an x and y value for every event, not from the event object at least. If you have a mouse event you'll do something like this:

```
if(event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved) 
{
    // do something with event.mouseMove.x and event.mouseMove.y
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to do this outside a `mouseMoved` event scope, you can always use the [`Mouse`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Mouse.php) class. This contains a `getPosition` method that will return a 2d vector containing `x` and `y`:

```
sf::Mouse::getPosition(); //Absolute coordinates
sf::Mouse::getPosition(window); //Relative to window
```